# How to return full list of arrays separately?

Tags: python, arrays, return

I have a function here called `factors` that I'm using to define a second function `permutations`. First `factors` here:

```
def factors(x):
    factors = []
    for x in range(1,x+1):
        factors.append(x)
    return factors
```

The next bit of code I'm using factors in is:

```
import itertools as it

def permutations(x):
    for p in it.permutations(factors(x)):
        return(np.array(p))
```

When I try to run `permutations(3)`, it returns:

`array([1 2 3])`

I can't seem to return all the rows and instead just get the first row of the array. I tried printing it, and printing works:

```
import itertools as it

for p in it.permutations(factors(3)):
    print(np.array(p))
```

This returns:

```
[1 2 3]
[1 3 2]
[2 1 3]
[2 3 1]
[3 1 2]
[3 2 1]
```

I think it has to do with how I'm returning, because I'm only asking for the first array, I'm not iterating it somehow to show all the arrays. I want it to return all the arrays as the return to my function.

Answer (score 3):

When your function encounters a return statement, it returns for good. Change the `return` to `yield` to make a generator:

```
def permutations(x):
    for p in it.permutations(factors(x)):
        yield np.array(p)
```

Demo:

```
>>> list(permutations(3))
[array([1, 2, 3]), array([1, 3, 2]), array([2, 1, 3]), array([2, 3, 1]), array([3, 1, 2]), array([3, 2, 1])]
```

Another thing: Your `factors` function is pointless. You can just use `range` to do the same thing, for example:

```
>>> range(1, 5)
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

So the line

```
for p in it.permutations(factors(x)):
```

should be written as

```
for p in it.permutations(range(1, x+1)):
```

Finally, if you are using Python 3.3 or newer, you can use the `yield from` syntax:

```
def permutations(x):
    yield from map(np.array, it.permutations(range(1, x+1)))
```

Comment: i tried `yield` and it returns this: `<generator object permutations at 0x10db4cf68>`. any ideas?

Comment: @MichaelHwang make a list out of the generator object. `list(permutations(3))`

Comment: i'm keeping the factors as a function cuz i need to call it elsewhere, but i can definitely simplify it by defining it as a `range(1,x+1)`. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelHwang no problem

Answer (score 1):

The `return` statement immediately terminates the function and returns to the caller. In your case that means it never gets to the second loop iteration.

Instead of a for loop:

```
for p in it.permutations(factors(x)):
    return(np.array(p))
```

Try using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to construct an array:

```
return [np.array(p) for p in it.permutations(factors(x))]
```